# Removing quotes in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have imported a CSV file to Access DB. In the imported files all the field values for each field are enclosed with quotes [screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWG73.jpg)

Are there any way to remove this quotes from the table. Thank you

Comment: Does the CSV file itself contain the quotes ? If yes, you might want to try to do a Find & Replace on the CSV file using a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++ or WordPad for example). Your problem might happen because Excel itself sees the data as text, and not as, for example, numeric values. So, when you exported, since it interpreted it as text, it put quotes around it.

Comment: Yeah CSV it self contains quotes.But as its huge in size , its little hard to find and replace.

Comment: You should probably import the CSV properly (with quotes defined as string delimiter), instead of removing the quotes after import.

Comment: That's why I asked about the data type in Excel. You might have to explicitly say to Excel what is the type of each column before exporting, so that it doesn't see it as text. Because, even without string delimiters, Double numbers and such shouldn't be seen as String to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the quote with an empty string (after importing as-is):
`SELSCT Replace(MyField, chr(34), "") FROM MyCsvTable`
Or:
`UPDATE MyCsvTable SET MyField = Replace(MyField, chr(34), "")`
[Replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php) replaces a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters
[Chr](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/chr.php) returns the character of the [ASCII](https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php) code, sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

I Have got the answer, there is an option of selecting "Text Qualifier" during the Import which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx [marlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6065909/marlan). This worked.
I have column with some names starting with 1 quote mark.

In Query Design editor i created `Nav: Replace([name];Chr(34);"")` into new field and started from there.

[image]

[image]

And just copy/paste Nav column over name column. :)